# What do I get back from Tesseract when OCR a Checkbox (not a form)

Tags: tesseract

We parse a good number of PDFs, from many vendors. The PDFs are similar, but not exactly the same and things are not always in an exact same position on the same page. Some cases we are able to parse via getting the Strings from the PDF and checkboxes are Unicode. However, many vendors are not using Unicode so an image. These are never forms. So if I use iText to OCR the whole document, what does it produce for these checkboxes? Such that I can look for that and see if a checkbox is checked or not? Or am I just out of luck and the only way the data gets into our application is through manual entry? Thanks.

Comment: "So if I use iText to OCR the whole document" - I'm not finding any documentation to suggest that iText provides OCR functionality.

Comment: I am an iText employee and I can confirm what @TheBlueFish wrote: *currently* (as of February 2018) iText does not yet provide OCR functionality. You may want to take a look at Tesseract (originally by HP, now sponsored by Google) which is an open source OCR API which is very accurate, but it is also very bare-bones. You'd need to write your own wrapper around it, or get someone else to do that for you.

Comment: Thanks Sorry. I was using Tessaract to do the OCR. The other parsing we are using is iText. But we are now getting PDFs that have some pages scanned in and some as PDF types.

Comment: @user1567291 Were you able to get the value for the checkbox? I have a similar situation as yours.

Comment: @adarshhegde Nope, a couple years in and we still have the same problem. Our business team has to spend a good avg 40 hours a week to manually enter in the data because we cannot read the checkboxes being checked.

Comment: @user1567291 Thank you for the reply. I wonder if you tried OpenCV. I haven't tried implementing this using Opencv but looking at the concepts I feel text recognition and image recognition(checkbox) should be possible.

Comment: @adarshhegde I don't have months to learn Machine Learning and a whole library to try and figure it out. And might be too much overkill.